# How can i format aspx-markup as html to show it on webpage

Tags: asp.net, markup, visual-studio-addins, html-generation

i've been using C. Coller's excellent [CopyAsHtml-Visual Studio addin](http://www.jtleigh.com/people/colin/software/CopySourceAsHtml/) for copying C# code as html to a webpage.

Now, i started to wonder if there exists a similar tool for converting the aspx-markup to valid html to show on page? Functionality that i'm looking for can be seen on [G. Houston's blog](http://formatmysourcecode.blogspot.com/).

F.ex. if i feed this

```
<asp:Button id="btnSthing" runat="server"></button>
```

into the tool in link above, it generates the following for me:

```
<pre style="font-family: Andale Mono, Lucida Console, Monaco, fixed, monospace; color:     
#000000; background-color: #eee;font-size: 12px;border: 1px dashed #999999;line-height: 
14px;padding: 5px; overflow: auto; width: 100%"><code>&lt;asp:Button id=&quot;
btnSthing&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot;&gt;&lt;/button&gt;</code></pre>
```

and i can simply copy and paste this into a website to show the aspx-markup used.

If there's a tool for this sort of functionality, that would integrate into VS, i'd like to hear about it! Other methods for achieving this effect would be greatly appreciated too!

greets,
J.Arola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a tool for VS, but the following website allows you to have source code from several languages (C#, Java, PHP, XML, HTML, ASPX) formatted for HTML:
http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/FormatCode.aspx